# Rails checkbox and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, parameters

I am using many checkboxes in a page as the following:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:one, value = 1) %></p>
```

Imagine that it goes from 1 to 20, all the same with the value changed. How can I get in the controller the `params` of the ones that were checked?

Example: If user checks 3, 5 and 10 how can I get just those params in a single params?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll *already* get only the ones that were checked; unchecked boxes aren't sent to the server.

Comment: But how can I get them from just a single params? Just does not seems right to get it using a lot of params.

Comment: @ArthurWilson Not sure what you mean. If they're all named the same thing don't they come as an array? (I don't recall off the top of my head, sorry.)

Comment: Like if I name them `:numbers[]` and call `params(:numbers)` it will work?

Comment: @ArthurWilson The name shouldn't include the colon, but yes, I think so--why not just try it?

Comment: Actually I did `'numbers[]'` and got the params as `params[:numbers]`. Thanks for the help.