# how to check check_box_tag is checked or not in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

how to check check_box_tag is checked or not in rails?

I need to know what checkboxes is checked.

This system is to users generate reports baseds on options selects.

View:

```
<%= form_tag finish_reports_path do %>
    <div class="row top30 reload">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <%= check_box_tag("name", "1", false, class: "checkbox") %>
                <%= label_tag :name, "Nome do Conteúdo" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <%= check_box_tag(:url, "2", false, class: "checkbox") %>
                <%= label_tag :url, "URL do Conteúdo" %>
            </div>
            <%= link_to t("button.generate"), finish_reports_path(finish: "yes"), :class => "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
   def index
    end

    def finish
        redirect_to root_path
    end
```

Routes:

```
root "reports#index"
post "/" => "reports#read_combo", as: :read_reports_combo

get "/reports/generate/:type" => "generate#index", as: :reports_generate
get "/reports/generate" => "generate#finish", as: :finish_reports
```

Comment: Read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html on how use Rails form helpers and access the params hash from your finish method

Comment: @Bryce I Read this article, but don't understand how use :( help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code in View:

```
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <%= check_box_tag("name[]", "i18n.name", false, class: "checkbox") %>
                    <%= label_tag :name, "Nome do Conteúdo" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <%= check_box_tag("name[]", "url.url", false, class: "checkbox") %>
                    <%= label_tag :url, "URL do Conteúdo" %>
                </div>
```

And this in Controller:

```
@properties = params["name"]
```

And solved =D!!

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox isn't checked, no params are passed, meaning the value is false. If the checkbox gets checked, the params will show up in the controller. If you want to pass the falsy value to the params, create a hidden field with the `hidden_input` value set to `false`. 
I believe this is a duplicate. [Rails checkbox and params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870090/rails-checkbox-and-params)

Comment: But if I just input a hidden_input when I get check or unchecked value? and how i get the this value?

Comment: I look the other post and don't understant to

Comment: you set the value of the hidden_input to false, something like:

Comment: `<div class="form-inline">
      <%= check_box_tag("name", "1", false, class: "checkbox") %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag("name", false) %>
      <%= label_tag :name, "Nome do Conteúdo" %>
    </div>`

Comment: I add "hidden_field_tag" in two checkbox with different names.

After select one checkbox and press submit_tag, the parameters return false for two tags.

Help Me please